# Nginx: NonWWW (80) and rewrite one subdomain (443)

Tags: ssl, nginx, url-rewriting, subdomain, port

I have 'www.domain.com' and want to always rewrite it to 'domain.com' (only available through/on port 80)

I also wanted to add subdomain like 'c.domain.com', always rewrited (and only available) to 'https://c.domain.com', but i don't really know how to make another rewrite when i have this for WWW->NonWWW.

This is my config:

```
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/server.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/server.key;

server  {
        listen                     80;
        server_name                www.domain.com;
        # redirect www to non-www
        rewrite                    ^/(.*) http://domain.com/$1 permanent;   
}



server {
        listen                     80;
        server_name                domain.com;
        root                       /usr/share/nginx/$host;
        index                      index.php index.html index.htm;

        location / {
                try_files          $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args =404;
                #try_files          $uri $uri/;
        }

        # PHP-FPM
        location ~* \.php$ {
                try_files          $uri =404;
                include            fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_pass       unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_param      SCRIPT_FILENAME     $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param      SCRIPT_NAME         $fastcgi_script_name;
        }

}

server {
  listen           443 default_server ssl;
  server_name      c.domain.com;
  root                       /usr/share/nginx/$host;
  index                      index.php index.html index.htm;

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
server  {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.domain.com;

    return 301 http://domain.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  domain.com;

    [...]
}

server  {
    listen       80;
    server_name  c.domain.com;

    return 301 https://c.domain.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen       443 default_server ssl;
    server_name  c.domain.com;

    [...]
}
```

Documentation:

- http://nginx.org/r/server_name
- http://nginx.org/r/return
- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html
- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html